# Wait for iframe to load that has been dynamically added to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using jQuery 3.5.1 to append an iframe to the bottom of a page after a form has been submitted and I want to take action *after* the iframe has loaded, but I can't seem to find a listener that works.

The iframe is loading fine via this:

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="ubaConversion" src="https://www.example.com" style="display: none"></iframe>');
```

But this code isn't working to report when the frame is done loading:

```
$(function(){       
    $('#ubaConversion').load(function(){
        console.log('iframe loaded successfully')
    });
});
```

I'm guessing it's due to the frame being appended after the page loads? Or can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

**EDIT—full deployment below**

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//wwww.example.com", "123-456-7891", 1234, function(form) {
//Add an onSuccess handler
form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl) {
    // Register conversion
    $('body').append('<iframe id="ubaConversion" src="https://wwww.example.com/" style="display: none"></iframe>');
  
    return false;
  });                      
});

$(function(){       
    $('#ubaConversion').on('load', function() {
        console.log('iframe loaded successfully')
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  This is important because 3x changed the behavior of `load()`

Comment: ... so to be compatible with all jQuery versions [since v1.7](https://api.jquery.com/on/), use `.on('load', function() { ...` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shoybzv7/)

Comment: @Taplar using 3.5.1

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/load/ As of 3x, `load()` is not an even handler.  It is short hand for making an ajax call and putting the results in the element you call `load()` on.  As blex said, you have to use the `on()` version for the load event handler.

Comment: @Taplar changed it to the fiddle demo but it's still not working. I added the full context of how the iframe is being appended -- it's happening within an onsuccess handler from the Marketo form

Comment: If that's the case then you're attempt to bind on it on page load (with the use of a document ready) will most likely happen before that onsuccess handler happens.  So it will not exist at that point.

Comment: @Taplar is there a way to bind it after the append/onsuccess?

Comment: Not if the ajax promise isn't exposed.